# Copy multiple CSV files to SQL Server tables using PowerShell, each CSV is named same as table name

Tags: sql-server, powershell, function, csv, sqlbulkcopy

I want to move `.CSV` files data into SQL Server tables, the name of `.CSV` file is `schema.TableName`. Thus the names of `.CSV` file and the target table are the same.

I am using SQL bulk copy. Script is not moving data to the database, also no error is generated. I have tried troubleshooting but cannot find why it is not copying data to database. Also I do not have much knowledge of PowerShell script, so I'm looking for some help.

```
# Function to import CSV data into SQL Server table
function Import-CsvToSqlServer {
    param (
        [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection]$connection,
        [string]$csvFilePath
    )
    try {
        
        $tableName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($csvFilePath)
        Write-Host $csvFilePath                                                         #Check Code
        Write-Host "$($tableName) getting loaded"                                       #Check Code
        $csvData = Import-Csv -Path $csvFilePath | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty Type
        $sqlbulkCopy = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($connection, [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions]::TableLock)
        $sqlbulkCopy.EnableStreaming = $true
        $sqlbulkCopy.BatchSize=50000
        $sqlbulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout=0
        $sqlbulkCopy.DestinationTableName = $tableName
        $sqlbulkCopy.WriteToServer($csvData)
        Write-Host "CSV data from $($csvFile.Name) imported into SQL Server table $($tableName) successfully."
        Move-Item -Path $csvFilePath -Destination $archiveFolderPath -Force
        Write-Host "CSV file $($csvFile.Name) moved to archive folder successfully."
    } catch {
        Send-EmailNotification -recipient "recipient@example.com" -subject "Error Notification" -body "Failed to import CSV data into SQL Server table $($tableName): $_"
    }
}

# Main script
try 
{
    # Connect to SQL Server
    $sqlConnection = ConnectTo-SqlServer
   
    # Get list of CSV files in the folder
    $csvFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $csvFolderPath -Filter *.csv
    if ($csvFiles.Count -eq 0) 
    {
        Write-Host "No CSV files found in the folder."
        exit
    }
    
    # Iterate through CSV files
    foreach ($csvFile in $csvFiles) 
    {
       Write-Host "Import started"
        Import-CsvToSqlServer -connection $sqlConnection -csvFilePath $csvFile.
        Write-Host "Import Completed"
    }
}
```

Comment: What does appear in the output? Are the `Write-Host` lines appearing? Are you sure `ConnectTo-SqlServer` worked? `$null -eq $SqlConnection`

Comment: Shouldn't you need to convert the array of PsCustomObjects in `$csvData` to a DataTable first so it is in an accepted format for `WriteToServer()`

Comment: Check the server log files by using SQL Server Management Studio.  The log files are in the explorer under Management.  There should be a login for every powershell query to server

Comment: Try the [DbaTools library](https://docs.dbatools.io/Write-DbaDbTableData.html), it's a simple `Get-ChildItem -Path SomePath | For-Each { $csv = Import-Csv $_; Write-DbaDbTableData -SqlInstance YourServer -Database YourDb -InputObject $csv -Table $_.Name -AutoCreateTable; }`

Comment: Hello can anyone please elaborate here. Thank you